# Multiple implementations of IExceptionHandler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

What is the best way to handle multiple implementations of `IExceptionHandler` in WebAPI?

```cs
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new ExceptionHandlerFilter());
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new ValidationExceptionHandlerFilter());
```

When attempting to register more than 1 implementation, the startup throws an exception:

> The service type IExceptionHandler is not supported.\r\nParameter name: serviceType

But the API suggests multiple handlers are supported since there's a `ShouldHandle` property to override on `ExceptionHandler` class.

Answer (score 4):

You can't register more the a `IExceptionHandler`

> We support registering multiple exception loggers but only a single exception handler.

source:[Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)

The `ShouldHandle` properties is used to get only the exception at the top of the stack

Comment: Yeah, such a shame, had to solve this with using the handler as a factory and look up the exception in a bunch of classes and let the correct class handle it. Worked out well in the end.